# Повернуть игрока в определённую точку

Tags: python, геометрия

Есть три точки, (x0,y0) - центр, нулевые координаты, (x2, y2) - игрок, (x1, y1) - точка, в которую необходимо повернуть игрока.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Известны координаты всех точек, дистанция до них, и текущий угол поворота игрока.

Пытался найти информацию в гугле, но даже не знаю как правильно составить вопрос.
Пишу на Python, но мне необязательно код, нужно хотя бы примерное описание как это сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Направление от (x2,y2) на (x1,y1) —

```
tg φ = (y1-y2)/(x1-x2)
```

Не знаю, как в Python, но в C/C++ с поиском угла лучше всего справится функция [`atan2`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/atan2).

Ну, а найти угол поворота — так это просто разность угла нового направления и текущего...

P.S. Ага, в Python [такая же функция](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_math_atan2.asp).